# extjs grid locked column render in the panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I simple write

```
text     : '...',
locked   : true,
width    : 230,
sortable : false,
dataIndex: 'hour'
```

And get it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EFCw.png

The column is render in the panel. With grid bbar.

Column config without "locked   : true" render normally

This happens in any theme.
And, of course, this does not happen in the "empty" project

Ext.version

```
build: 883
major: 4
minor: 2
patch: 1
shortVersion: "421883"
version: "4.2.1.883"
```

Comment: Ouch. What version of Ext is that? 4.2.1? Have you tried with a previous version and/or another theme?

Answer (score 0):

From Ext documentation:

> A locking grid is processed in a special way. The configuration
>   options are cloned and two grids are created to be the locked (left)
>   side and the normal (right) side. This Panel becomes merely a
>   container which arranges both in an HBox layout.
>
> Plugins may be targeted at either locked, or unlocked grid, or, both,
>   in which case the plugin is cloned and used on both sides.
>
> Plugins may also be targeted at the containing locking Panel.
>
> This is configured by specifying a lockableScope property in your
>   plugin which may have the following values:
>
> "both" (the default) - The plugin is added to both grids
>   "top" - The plugin is added to the containing Panel
>   "locked" - The plugin is added to the locked (left) grid
>   "normal" - The plugin is added to the normal (right) grid

See:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-enableLocking